# Collision issues that I can't find the answer to

Tags: unreal-development-kit, collision, unrealscript

I'm in dire need of help. I've had UDK for several months but continuously run into problems.

In a nutshell I'm trying to make my own video game using UDK as the game engine. In 3ds max 2013 I have created two entire houses that I've been trying to import into UDK to then be able to walk around in and eventually code events and all that.

My main issue right now is I'm trying to import the front lawn (literally a near flat plane) with a custom collision I made using the video tutorial here - http://www.3dmotive.com/training/fre...k/?follow=true
 I know this tutorial is old but I thought it would work - it won't for me - the collision model doesn't register and it seems the collision box I made in 3ds enveloped the actual plane.

So I'm looking for as much help as I can get! Is anyone has suggestions on this specifically you are deemed epic and awesome, and those who have tips or tutorials or whatever that is recent (for the July 2012 UDK beta release) I will love you forever.

Please help a newbie out!

Comment: As a unrealscript coder, I can assure you that your problem is not related to unrealscript. I suggest asking at the [offical UDK forum](http://forums.epicgames.com/forums/366-UDK), there are the most UDK users there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to import a mesh into UDK it must be in ASE file format.

Is it in the proper format? if so check your export settings and play with those.

UDK has an in engine collision generator as well which is simple to use and a useful tool.

You can use it by going to the static mesh properties toggle on collision and generate new collision.

(the link you provided does not work).